# Query does not populate list in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, neo4j, graph-databases

I have a problem with executing Neo4j @Query in my Spring Boot project. When I run query in Neo4j app it returns expected values, but when I execute it in Spring Boot it doesn't seem to work, and returns empty array. Here is my code:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Train {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private Integer number;

    @Relationship(type = "STOPS", direction = OUTGOING)
    List<Station> stations = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Station> getStations(){
        return stations;
    }

    public Train(){

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(Integer number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

```
@Repository
public interface TrainRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Train, Long> {

    @Query("MATCH (u:Train)-[r:STOPS]->(m:Station) RETURN u, r, m")
    Collection<Train> getAllTrains();
}
```

I don't know what might be the problem.

Comment: Does adding a setter on stations solve the issue by any chance?

Comment: @fbiville No, I have already tried that

Answer (score 0):

@Repository
public interface TrainRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Train, Long> {

```
@Query("MATCH (u:Train)-[r:STOPS]->(m:Station) RETURN u, r, m")
Collection<Train> getAllTrains();
```

}

change above to like this..

@Repository
public interface TrainRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Train, Long> {

```
@Query("MATCH (u:Train)-[r:STOPS]->(m:Station) RETURN u, r, m")
List<Train> getAllTrains();
```

}